# issue in script for server log analysis

Tags: shell, hp-ux

I want to do server.log analysis for error and i want before 10 line and after 10 line of that error so below script is giving error in **Hp-ux**,please provide alternate solution:

**grep  -A 10 -B 10 "ERROR" server.log >> /tmp/Test.log**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
grep -A10 -B10 -P "ERROR" server.log >> /tmp/Test.log
```

Comment: grep: illegal option -- A
grep: illegal option -- 1
grep: illegal option -- 0
grep: illegal option -- B
grep: illegal option -- 1
grep: illegal option -- 0
grep: illegal option -- P
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvwx] pattern [file...]

Answer (score 0):

Since the old `grep` hasn't the convenient `-ABC` options, the solution is a little more complicated:

```
grep -n "ERROR" server.log | sed 's/\([0-9]*\):.*/\1-10<=NR\&\&NR<=\1+10{print;next}/' \
                           | awk -f- server.log >>/tmp/Test.log
```

This uses `sed -n` to get the line numbers and a `sed`-generated `awk` script to print the context.